# I cannot be an admin anymore?

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I tried to make an authentication page with Laravel and I simply made it with `php artisan make:auth`

The code was generated into Controllers and as view, in */resources/views/auth*. I moved the folder into another folder: */resources/views/admin/auth* and now I get this error:

> View [auth.login] not found.

For routes I used: `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`

What can I do now?

Comment: Try to clear cache with php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks for a view under `/views/auth/login`, however you moved the files to `/views/admin/auth` - everything is under **admin**.

You have to move the views back up one directory, or customise the routes in the AuthController.